# ICMP Checksum offload

Tags: checksum, icmp

I have a simple custom ping program echo request / echo reply....Server part is deployed in Linux and client is in Windows machine....

Both client and server side programatically calculating  ICMP check sum and setting it ..All are ok .

Now I want to enable ICMP check sum offload to Network card for Server module ....I have already enabled it using ethtool

I can see for TCP, Check sum offloading happening ......But when I comment out ICMP check sum calculation part from server program  hoping Network card will do for me But I am not getting any Echo reply....Though Server is receiving Echo request....It must be for wrong check sum packet being dropped...

Can anybody show me the way.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know the `NIC checksum offloading` can only mangle `IP/TCP/UDP` frames.

I don't think `ICMP` frame is covered.