# Issue ICMP checksum XDP

Tags: linux, checksum, ebpf, icmp

I am asking for your help regarding an error I have been experiencing for two weeks now.

I am working on a NAT64 implemented in XDP using BCC, the exchange between nodes works, my sender node sends the ping and the receiver node receives the ping, in between the two nodes there is another node called `router` where there is attached the XDP program. In one interface it translates from ipv6 to ipv4 and another interface does ipv4 to ipv6.
The node are namespaces.

The problem occurs when the destination node receives the packet, the ICMP checksum I see from tcpdump is wrong (the ip checksum is not checked so I don't know if that one is right).

I've tried so many different approaches to calculate the checksum that I found scattered around the internet but none of them worked, I'm starting to think that maybe the error might be somewhere else?
So I've been checking and rechecking the code these past two weeks but can't find anything wrong.

This is my output from `tcpdump -i veth1 -vvv`:

```
16:10:45.883038 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    192.168.9.1 > archiz-linux: ICMP echo request, id 47244, seq 1, length 64 (wrong icmp cksum 3f72 (->6fc9)!)
```

I tried to disable the checksum offload with: `ethtool -K veth rx off tx off` for every veths in every namespaces but I have the same previous output. Maybe it didn't work because this approch don't cover the icmp checksum like this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790836/icmp-checksum-offload) says.

The checksum calculation function:

**csum_fold_helper()**

```
static inline __u16 csum_fold_helper(__u64 csum)
{
    __u32 sum;
    sum = (csum >> 16) + (csum & 0xffff);
    sum += (sum >> 16);
    return ~sum;
}
```

And this is my implementation, I omitted parts for simplicity:

```
int xdp_router_func(struct xdp_md *ctx){
    void *data = (void *)(long)ctx->data;
    void *data_end = (void *)(long)ctx->data_end;

    struct bpf_fib_lookup fib_params = {0};

    struct ethhdr eth_cpy;
    struct ethhdr *eth = data;
    struct iphdr *iph = {0};

    __u64 nh_off = sizeof(*eth);

    if (data + nh_off > data_end)
        return XDP_DROP;

    if (eth->h_proto == bpf_htons(ETH_P_IPV6))
    {

        memcpy(&eth_cpy, eth, sizeof(eth_cpy));

        struct ipv6hdr *ip6h = data + nh_off;
        if (ip6h + 1 > data_end)
            return XDP_DROP;

        ...


        struct iphdr dst_hdr = {
            .version = 4,
            .ihl = 5,
            .frag_off = bpf_htons(1 << 14),
        };

        __u32 assigned_ipv4 = 0;

        // search inside the natting_table the ipv6_addr associated to the ipv4
        ...

        dst_hdr.saddr = bpf_htonl((__be32)assigned_ipv4);
        dst_hdr.daddr = ip6h->daddr.s6_addr32[3];

        dst_hdr.protocol = ip6h->nexthdr;
        dst_hdr.ttl = ip6h->hop_limit;
        dst_hdr.tos = ip6h->priority << 4 | (ip6h->flow_lbl[0] >> 4);
        dst_hdr.tot_len = bpf_htons(bpf_ntohs(ip6h->payload_len) + sizeof(dst_hdr));

        // check if the packet is a icmpv6
        if (dst_hdr.protocol == IPPROTO_ICMPV6)
        {
            struct icmp6hdr *icmp6h = (void *)ip6h + sizeof(*ip6h);
            if (icmp6h + 1 > data_end)
                return XDP_DROP;

            // ready to parse the icmpv6 header in icmp
            struct icmphdr tmp_icmp;
            struct icmphdr *icmp;

            // set the right type to icmp, id field and sequence field
            if (write_icmp(&tmp_icmp, icmp6h) == -1)
            {
                bpf_trace_printk("[ERR]: error during icpmv6 parse in icmp");
                return XDP_DROP;
            }

            if (bpf_xdp_adjust_head(ctx, (int)sizeof(*icmp6h) - (int)sizeof(tmp_icmp)))
                return XDP_DROP;

            // after the adjust head I have to reassign the pointers
            data = (void *)(long)ctx->data;
            data_end = (void *)(long)ctx->data_end;

            icmp = (void *)(data + sizeof(struct ethhdr) + sizeof(struct ipv6hdr));
            if (icmp + 1 > data_end)
                return XDP_DROP;

            *icmp = tmp_icmp;

            // set the checksum
            icmp->checksum = 0x0000;
            icmp->checksum = csum_fold_helper(bpf_csum_diff((__be32 *)icmp, 0, (__be32 *)icmp, sizeof(icmp), 0));

            dst_hdr.protocol = IPPROTO_ICMP;

        } // icmpv6

        dst_hdr.check = csum_fold_helper(bpf_csum_diff((__be32 *)&dst_hdr, 0, (__be32 *)&dst_hdr, sizeof(dst_hdr), 0));

        if (bpf_xdp_adjust_head(ctx, (int)sizeof(struct ipv6hdr) - (int)sizeof(struct iphdr)))
            return XDP_DROP;

        // after the adjust head I have to reassign the pointers
        eth = (void *)(long)ctx->data;
        data = (void *)(long)ctx->data;
        data_end = (void *)(long)ctx->data_end;

        if (eth + 1 > data_end)
            return XDP_DROP;

        memcpy(eth, &eth_cpy, sizeof(*eth));
        eth->h_proto = bpf_htons(ETH_P_IP);


        iph = (void *)(data + sizeof(*eth));

        if (iph + 1 > data_end)
        {
            bpf_trace_printk("iph out of boundary");
            return XDP_DROP;
        }

        *iph = dst_hdr;
        // start forwarding

        // setting the fib_params
        fib_params.family = AF_INET;
        fib_params.tos = iph->tos;
        fib_params.tot_len = bpf_ntohs(iph->tot_len);
        fib_params.ipv4_dst = iph->daddr;
        fib_params.ipv4_src = iph->saddr;
        fib_params.ifindex = ctx->ingress_ifindex;
        fib_params.sport = 0;
        fib_params.dport = 0;

    } // end ipv6

    // forwarding
    int rc;
    rc = bpf_fib_lookup(ctx, &fib_params, sizeof(fib_params), 0);
    switch (rc)
    {
    case BPF_FIB_LKUP_RET_SUCCESS: /* lookup successful */
        memcpy(eth->h_dest, fib_params.dmac, ETH_ALEN);
        memcpy(eth->h_source, fib_params.smac, ETH_ALEN);

        
        int action;
        action = bpf_redirect(fib_params.ifindex, 0);
        return action;
        
     // other cases
        ...
    }

  return XDP_PASS;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Cilium implements such a checksum calculation](https://github.com/cilium/cilium/blob/103077d3ecf826b9329a02f7c0c0db8190452fe7/bpf/lib/lb.h#L1802-L1858), so I'd use that (with proper attribution and copyleft license):

```c
csum = icmp_wsum_accumulate(icmp_payload, icmp_payload_end, ctx_full_len(ctx));
csum += csum_diff(icmp, 0, icmp, sizeof(struct icmphdr), 0);
icmp->checksum = csum_fold(csum);

static __always_inline __sum16 csum_fold(__wsum csum)
{
    csum = (csum & 0xffff) + (csum >> 16);
    csum = (csum & 0xffff) + (csum >> 16);
    return (__sum16)~csum;
}
```

`icmp_wsum_accumulate` is [defined in the sources](https://github.com/cilium/cilium/blob/103077d3ecf826b9329a02f7c0c0db8190452fe7/bpf/lib/lb.h#L2058) (and is what I believe requires attribution and GPL-compatible licensing). `icmp_payload` and `icmp_payload_end` should point to the start and end of your ICMP message payload (typically the original IP packet).

Comment: thank you very much, I tried several different parameters, and it still doesn't work :(
I think the most correct one is as in the cilium implementation ie.
icmp_payload = data + sizeof(struct ethhdr)
icmp_payload_end = data_end
sample_len = data_end - data
also with values other than icmp_payload_end the verifier complains.

Comment: Without a minimal, reproducible example, it's going to be difficult to debug.

Comment: So sorry if I am not helpful, I'm truly grateful for your help. I just substituted your advice to the "set the cheksum" part of the code in the post and added the "icmp_wsum_accumulate" function without changing it. 
I call the function like this:             
csum = icmp_wsum_accumulate(data + sizeof(struct ethhdr), data_end, data_end - data);

Comment: I hope it is not a problem to use "data_end - data" instead of ctx_full_len. The latter gives me error for asm instruction